# Can not get the scope variable properly

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have a simple text box and a button and whenever user click on button the alert shows the text of textbox but I want to do it this way(I know there are a lot better ways but first I want to understand why this way does not work):

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.factory('Service', function() {
    var service = {
            add: add
        };
        return service;
        function add($scope) {
            alert($scope.user.username);
        }
});
app.controller('table', function(Service,$scope) {
    //get the return data from getData funtion in factory
    this.add = Service.add($scope);

});
```

As you can see I send the scope to factory and I define the user.username as follow:

```
    <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="t.add(user.userName)">
```

But when I run this nothing happens can anyone tell me what is wrong with this code?

```
<body ng-app="app">
<form>
    <div class="row commonRow" ng-controller="table as t">
        <div class="col-xs-1 text-right">item:</div>
        <div class="col-lg-6 text-right">
            <input id="txt" type="text" style="width: 100%;"
                ng-model="user.userName">
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-2">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="t.add(user.userName)">
                click me</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

also the plnk link is as follow:

[plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/nzLWG0XG7I5r2VxDaC8v?p=preview)

Comment: you are mixing concerns here; you are trying to pass a variable to the service through `$scope`, but you are trying to call the service using the alternate Controller As syntax.  If you inspect your code, you'll see that `user.userName` is undefined because `user` doesn't exist on `$scope`.  once that is solved, you'll also see that your function isn't firing.

Comment: Thank u @Claies can you privide the plnkr of working version of this code?

Comment: @Claies also in this line I am difining the variable in scope: <input id="txt" type="text" style="width: 100%;"
     ng-model="user.userName">

Comment: I think as has been pointed out in multiple answers and in your question itself, this isn't the right way to accomplish your task.  Trying to "fix" a solution that isn't right for the problem domain in the first place is an example of the XY Problem.  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in this line

```
this.add = Service.add($scope);
```

Here you are assigning the returned (which is `undefined`) value of the `Service.add($scope)` invocation to the `this.add`.

The right approach will be either

```
this.add = function(data) { Service.add($scope); }
```

or

```
this.add = Service.add;

// in the service factory.
function add(usrNm) {
    alert(usrNm);
}
```

Comment: Thank you please take look I did what you said but still the same problem : http://plnkr.co/edit/abZhudS7VXIIHsWQGAQD?p=preview

Comment: @HamedMinaee, in this plunker code it should be `alert(usrNm.user.userName);`

Comment: Thank u just out of curiosity I tried this instead of first one: this.add=Service.add but seems that it does not work what is wrong with that: http://plnkr.co/edit/abZhudS7VXIIHsWQGAQD?p=preview

Comment: @HamedMinaee. In this one it should be `alert(usrNm);`. Because when the button is clicked the userName value is passed to controller's add method which in turn **is** the method of service. So service's add method has a username value as argument. I also updated the answer to hopefully indicate these difference.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing is you can't use $scope in a service.and in controller your not assaining this(object) to $scope.so $scope doesn't contain any value.
I suppose you to write like this
        $scope.user = this;

Comment: can you provide fiddle or plnkr link?

Comment: can you tell me your requirement

Comment: I want to make the link above that I provided work , but in a way that it is , I want to understand why it is not working...